# Rotating a QLabel with Mouse Drag

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am sub-classing a `QLabel` and am trying to rotate it as the user drags (or rotates) an image with the mouse. Currenty I am just rotating clock-wise with every mouse moved event:

```
void RotoTest::slotMouseMoved()
{
    currentRotation += 1;
    rotate(currentRotation % 360);
}

void RotoTest::rotate(int degree)
{
    QPixmap pixmap(originalPixmap);
    QPixmap rotatedMap(pixmap.size());
    QPainter p(&rotatedMap);
    p.translate(pixmap.size().width() / 2, pixmap.size().height() / 2);
    p.rotate(degree);
    p.translate(-pixmap.size().width() / 2, -pixmap.size().height() / 2);
    p.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap);
    this->setPixmap(rotatedMap);
}
```

This works and rotates, but the problem is that the image becomes very laggy, jittery and unresponsive, especially the quicker or longer the mouse is moved for a given instance. I suspect this is happening due to the large amount of signals being sent when the mouse moves. Does anybody have any suggestions for a way for a nice smooth rotation? I am looking for the image to rotate as nicely as the `QDial` does.

Comment: Does it become more laggy with usage, or does it stay equally laggy?

Comment: @DarenW: With usage. Moving slow the rotation is pretty responsive, but moving a little quicker causes it to stutter.

Comment: I'm looking at sample code for other things involving repainting moving objects - they all have painter.save() and painter.restore() calls around the code to transform and draw. Maybe is relevant, maybe not...

Comment: @DarenW: Those are saving and restoring painter settings. Useful if you are passing a `QPainter` to a function, so that the painter returns with the settings it had when it was sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me without seeing more code, but possibly it is too many events piling up.  If that's the case, then 1) it's a surprise since Qt is supposed to quietly take care of compressing many identical events into a few and 2) you can do it yourself by throttling calls to update() in your slot code handling the input event. (Or, since you're subclassing QLabel, it would go *somewhere*...?)

See http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/12257 for explanation and code.

Then again, this could be barking up the wrong tree entirely.  That's why we have downvote buttons ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "throttling calls to update()"? Are you perhaps suggesting waiting for the mouse to move a certain distance before repainting?

Comment: Nevermind, I am new to Qt and didn't know about the `update()` function. Thanks a ton, that link led to the answer.

Comment: Qt is not compressing random events, that would be a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you should only do expensive operations, like painting on a pixmap, within the `paintEvent()`. Your `slotMouseMoved()` should look like:

```
void slotMouseMoved() {
     currentRotation = (currentRotation + 1) % 360;
     update();
}
```

The pixmap generation should be done within the reimplemented `paintEvent()`. There's no reason to derive from QLabel, simply derive from QWidget.

```
void RotoTest::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * ev)
{
    QPixmap pixmap(originalPixmap);
    QPainter p(this);
    p.translate(pixmap.size().width() / 2, pixmap.size().height() / 2);
    p.rotate(degree);
    p.translate(-pixmap.size().width() / 2, -pixmap.size().height() / 2);
    p.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap);
}
```